# Relative Layout - android - Make a Relative Layout Scrollable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am making a Speed Dial App, which has Emergency Numbers hard-coded in it. Using nested `Relative Layout` and made a list of numbers. 
Below is the Emergency Numbers Page.

This is a Page of Dialer App, where it has a dialer and this is the Speed Dial Section Fragment which is not scrollable.

[image]

Below is my XML fragment for the above image.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">



   <!-- Relative Layouts Emergency Numbers Here - Logic - Increment Nums by 1-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2">



        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNama"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_marginTop="12px"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Emergency Number 1"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Call"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_blue_rounded_shadow"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/btnPolisi"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNama1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_marginTop="12px"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Emergency Number 2"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Call"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_blue_rounded_shadow"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/btnRS"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout5"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNama2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_marginTop="12px"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Emergency Number 3"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Call"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_blue_rounded_shadow"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/btnFire"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout7"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNama3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_marginTop="12px"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Emergency Number 4"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Call"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_blue_rounded_shadow"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/btnEmg4"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout9"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout7"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNama4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_marginTop="12px"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Emergency Number 5"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Call"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_blue_rounded_shadow"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/btnEmg5"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout11"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout9"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNama5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_marginTop="12px"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Emergency Number 6"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Call"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_blue_rounded_shadow"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/btnEmg6"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout13"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout11"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNama6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_marginTop="12px"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Emergency Number 7"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Call"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_blue_rounded_shadow"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/btnEmg7"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried with the `ListView` inside the nested relative layout. And even the `scrollview` for the same, some were fatal when used. I may be using some absurd logic in this code, but the view is great for me, I just need this code to make the layout `scrollable`. Kindly let me know where I need to change in my code to make the page scrollable.//
When I posted this question few logical issues were there in my layouts, now I have framed it logically and it;s inside a Linear Layout.

It isnt working anyway.

Comment: In your top most relative view, the orientation tag seems to be an artifact of Linear Layout. You can probably remove that :)

Comment: Technically, that shouldnt be a problem. Anyways, I have tried it, Didn't work.

Comment: not saying its a problem, just saying its unnecessary.

Comment: May be, here I am looking for a solution what I asked for. No Offence.

Comment: Seeing the image attached, `RecyclerView` would be a much better choice, each item being a single row with a phone. Take into account that the layout for each item can be any layout you like. My advice would be to use another type of layout, as `RelativeLayout` is not very performant.

Comment: Updated the code, And it' s not working even in Linear Layout.

Comment: are you getting an exception? if yes, can you post the stack trace

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

           <RelativeLayout 
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="vertical">

                // Write here your whole code without writing first Relative Layout....

           </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your layout inside a Scroll View. But a scroll view can have only ONE direct child. So what you need to do is take you top most relative layout and put that inside a scroll view. Something like this:

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout7">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView5" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="NEW"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_marginTop="12px"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Emergency Number 3"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Call"
                android:id="@+id/btnFire"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_blue_rounded_shadow"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="NEW"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNama"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_marginTop="12px"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Emergency Number 1"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Call"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_blue_rounded_shadow"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/btnPolisi"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvnew"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="NEW"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvnew" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivscreenshot"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvwords"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ivscreenshot"
                android:layout_marginTop="12px"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Emergency Number 2"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Call"
                android:id="@+id/btnRS"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_blue_rounded_shadow"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout5"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout7"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvnew1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="NEW"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvnew1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvnew1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivscreenshot1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvwords1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ivscreenshot1"
                android:layout_marginTop="12px"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Emergency Number 4"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Call"
                android:id="@+id/btnEmg4"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_blue_rounded_shadow"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout8"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvnew2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="NEW"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvnew2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvnew2">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivscreenshot2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvwords2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ivscreenshot1"
                android:layout_marginTop="12px"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Emergency Number 5"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Call"
                android:id="@+id/btnEmg5"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_blue_rounded_shadow"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout11"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout8"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvnew3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="NEW"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvnew3"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvnew3">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivscreenshot3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvwords3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ivscreenshot3"
                android:layout_marginTop="12px"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Emergency Number 6"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Call"
                android:id="@+id/btnEmg6"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_blue_rounded_shadow"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout13"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout11"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvnew4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="NEW"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvnew4"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvnew4">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivscreenshot4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvwords4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ivscreenshot4"
                android:layout_marginTop="12px"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Emergency Number 7"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Call"
                android:id="@+id/btnEmg7"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_blue_rounded_shadow"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had tried this solution earlier -  ScrollView can host only one direct child

Comment: @RávîñdräPãwäskâr yes, that child will be your top-level `RelativeLayout`. So, `ScrollView` -> `RelativeLayout` -> other children

Comment: Well I got my issue solved not my changing my logic in layouts, -

Comment: Updating the code --- RL(main) -- SV - LL - RL(Children) </LL> </SV> </RL> Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do with code:

```
ScrollView scrollview = new ScrollView(this);
scrollview.addView(wView);
```